AutoCorrect Entry for Microsoft Outlook Not Being Removed Upon Deletion
I am running into this issue where there is an AutoCorrect Entry that I made through Microsoft Outlook and is only specific to Outlook that I do not want. I have deleted it multiple times, but for some reason it continues to exist upon reopening Outlook.
I thought the issue may be that I needed to open the NormalEmail.dotm file and see if it existed there. However, I did not see it there and I am at a loss for how it would be permanently deleted.
Could anyone please assist with this?

The reason why an AutoCorrect entry may not be deleted when you delete it in Microsoft Outlook is that the entry is stored in the AutoCorrect list and another possibility is that the entry is stored in the normal.dotm template file.
You can try a few steps to permanently remove the AutoCorrect entry:
Open Outlook and go to the File tab.
Click on Options and then Mail.
Click on the Spelling & Autocorrect button.
In the Autocorrect tab, look for the entry you want to delete and select it.
.
Click on the Delete button to remove the entry from the list.
.
Close Outlook and open Microsoft Word.
.
Go to the File tab and click on Options.
.
Click on Advanced and then scroll down to the Show Document Content section.
.
Click on the File Locations button.
.
In the File Locations dialog box, look for the entry you deleted from Outlook and select it.
.
Click on the Modify button and then select the folder that contains the normal.dotm template file.
.
Click on the Open button and then select the normal.dotm file.
.
Close the File Locations dialog box and click on OK to close the Word Options dialog box.
.
Close Word and restart Outlook.
.
